# Highchart: Paint the background of the graph with different colors below and above the line

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

Is there any way to paint the whole graph (fill entire background) with two different colors in highchart. Above the line with first color (e.g. blue) and second below the line (e. g. red). I want to paint that graph:

[Graph I want to paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQdAs.png)

Comment: I am not really sure what you would like to achieve. You are not changing background in your example. You are changing series color. It is possible to have multiple colors for one series in Highcharts. You can use zones array in this case. Here you can find information about zones:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.zones And here you can find simple example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/vsapjkgp/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I do not want to paint dots, but whole background of the graph with two different colors. Green line in my graph separates the colors. Above the line whole background of the graph have to be painted with one color (e.g. blue) and below with another (e.g. blue). Image I append does not show what I want to do but it is the plot without painting I want to do.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly you can use chart.backgroundColor and define it as gradient. Here you can see an example how it can work http://jsfiddle.net/htyseLu4/

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzBlachliński that is solution to my problem if line is straight. But I found another solution, because I will extend the chart to work also with non-straight lines. So I decided to use `chart.renderer.path` to fill background with polygons.

Comment: Of course, it is good idea to use this option, thank you for information about your idea :)